# How to send realm-returned data through retrofit2?

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2

I'm trying to send `dishList` to my service but it is stuck. Even if I get an object from `dishList` to `dl`, it doesn't work. **BUT** if I send `dl` as in the code shown below, it works. Therefore the problem is in realm-returned objects. How to send realm-returned data through retrofit2?

```
    RealmResults<Dish> realmResults = realm.where(Dish.class).findAll();
    List<Dish> dishList = realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size());
    List<Dish> dl = new ArrayList<>();
    dl.add(new Dish());
    mDishService.updateRepository(dishList).enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
            if (response.body()) {
                response.body();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

service method:

```
    @POST("/v1/dishes/repo/u")
    Call<Boolean> updateRepository(@Body List<Dish> dishes);
```

Comment: What is this doing? `if (response.body()) { response.body(); }`... How exactly isn't this working how you expect? What does `mDishService.updateRepository(dishList)` do any different than `mDishService.updateRepository(dl)`?

Comment: Please clarify "it is stuck" and "it doesn't work", what exactly happens? Are you seeing any exceptions in the logcat?

Comment: @cricket_007, @Egor problem is that realm datas can't serialized, that is why it is need to remove binding of realm from its objects as mine `realmResults` ny using `realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);`. It gives list without realm

Comment: Right, you need a regular list object to give to retrofit. I don't understand why your RealmObject classes cannot be annotated with Gson, though, so that shouldn't be a problem. You still haven't clarified "it is stuck"

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
mDishService.updateRepository(
    realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Dish.class).findAll())
).enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
```

This is pretty much the only use-case in which `realm.copyFromRealm()` makes sense.